# Unable to Resolve Service for DbContext in UserService

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, .net-6.0

I have a UserService in my application that requires access to a DotNetDbContext, which is my Entity Framework DbContext for database operations. It seems that there's a problem with dependency injection and service resolution.

I can verify that the connection to the DB works, as i was able to seed it.

I'm encountering an issue while trying to initialize my services in my Blazor WebAssembly application. Specifically, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to resolve service for type 'Persistence.Data.DotNetDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Services.Users.UserService'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Persistence.Data.DotNetDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Services.Users.UserService'.
```

I would highly appreciate it if someone could find the problem within my code.

#### Startup.cs (Client)

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddSidepanel();


            //SERVICES
            builder.Services.AddProjectServices();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, FakeUserService>();


            //AUTHENTICATION
            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
                options.AddPolicy("Guest", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Guest"));
                options.AddPolicy("LoggedIn", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            });


            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
           
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationProvider>());
            builder.Services.AddTransient<AuthorizationMessageHandler>();


            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("AuthenticatedServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
           
            

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs (Server)

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public StartUp(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddProjectServices();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

            services.AddDbContext<DotNetDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer
                (
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")
                );
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddScoped<DotNetDataInitializer>();


        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DotNetDbContext dbContext, DotNetDataInitializer seeder)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();

            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });


            seeder.SeedData();
        }


        }

    }
```

#### Extension method used within Startup

```
namespace Services
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddProjectServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IFysiekeServerService, FakeServerService>();
            services.AddScoped<IProjectService, FakeProjectService>();
            services.AddScoped<IVirtualMachineService, FakeVirtualMachineService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();

            return services;
        }

    }
}
```

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "EntityFrameworkCore.Triggered": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Server=localhost;TrustServerCertificate=True;Database=DevOps;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

#### appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "EnableSqlParameterLogging": true
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Server=localhost;TrustServerCertificate=True;Database=DevOps;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

#### UserService.cs

```
    namespace Services.Users
    {
        public class UserService : IUserService
        {
            private DbSet<Klant> _klanten;
            private DbSet<Administrator> _admins;
    
            private readonly DotNetDbContext _dbContext;
    
            public UserService(DotNetDbContext dbContext)
            {
                this._dbContext = dbContext;
                this._klanten = dbContext.Klanten;
                this._admins = dbContext.Admins;
    
            }


### IUserService

namespace Shared.Users {

    public interface IUserService
    {
        Task<UserResponse.AllKlantenIndex> GetAllKlanten(UserRequest.AllKlantenIndex request);
        Task<UserResponse.DetailKlant> GetDetailKlant(UserRequest.DetailKlant request);
        Task<UserResponse.Edit> EditAsync(UserRequest.Edit request);
        Task<UserResponse.Create> CreateAsync(UserRequest.Create request);
        Task<UserResponse.CurrentUser> CurrentUserAsync();
        Task<UserResponse.LoginCredentials> GetLoginCredentials(string email);


    }
}
```

Comment: My Blazor knowledge is limited, but it looks like you are setting it up for WebAssembly but trying to use an EF DbContext. That almost certainly won't be as straight forward as in the case of a Server-based app as any DbContext instance in client-side code will not be able to just connect to a local, or necessarily server-based database.  I would start by searching up current info on using EF Core /w Blazor and WebAssembly. There are likely nuances and limitations depending on how far it is supported.

Comment: I have tried that indeed @Brian , the error remains the same though.

Comment: How is your IUserSerivce code?

Comment: Updated my question with the code